# Having problem with present contiunous and context

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context, tense-agreement

The river (flows/ is flowing) very fast today.

Do you know how to drive? 
I am learning (to). My father (teaches/is teaching) me.

Normally I finish work at five, but this week I (worked/am working) until six to earn a little more money.

In the above three questions, the choice between continuous and noncontiuous verb was made based on the context. But as a foreign learner of English, I have to a couple of questions;

1. In the second question is it correct to say 'I am learning to'?
2. In the second question, I'm assuming that  the 'my father is teaching me' refers to learning how to drive. So does that mean that even if his/her father taught him/her something else than driving, it is still appropriate to use 'is teaching' because it is only talking about the driving lesson?
3. In question 3, what if the time at which the person was talking was on the weekend? Then, should the person say 'worked' instead of 'working'??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: Do you know how to drive?
>
> A: I am learning how to drive.
>   My father is teaching me how to drive.
>   My father is teaching me how to chew gum and drive at the same time.

1. Yes, it is appropriate and usual to say "I am learning how to drive."
2. You can say "My father is teaching me..." for anything your father is teaching you, if it's other than driving it would be considered a *change of topic* in the conversation.
3. "**Worked**" for the week that just passed, "**am working**" for the coming week, just depends on *verb tense*.